Replace event.locals / page data with new data
In my SvelteKit app I fetch the user's info in the handle server hook, and store it in event.locals, much like the example in the official docmentation.
I have a +layout.server.ts file where I "forward" the locals to page data, like so:
import type { LayoutServerLoad } from "./$types";

export const load: LayoutServerLoad = async ({ locals }) => {
  return {
    flags: locals.flags,
    user: locals.user,
  };
};

And from there on the user object is accessible in any page via the page data. Great!
But now I have a form where the user can change their details, and the API returns the new user object. But it seems I can't store the new version of the user object anywhere, so the user still sees their old information throughout the website until they refresh the site - things like their avatar, name or email in the header of the site.
For example something like $page.data.user = newUserObject does not work, as $page is not a writeable store.
How can I store the new user object so that it's automatically used throughout the site, without the user having to do a refresh?

I did find an interesting question with an even more interesting answer: Creating a writable svelte store from loaded page data in sveltekit.
I can indeed do this in my +layout.ts file:
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const load = async ({ parent, data }) => {
    return {
        ...data,
        user: writable(data.user),
    };
};

And from then on the user property in my page data is a writable store. I have to make some changes to my routes to make it work with this store, but yeah it seems to work.
However, isn't it extremely unwise to return a store from the load function? Isn't this going to be shared across multiple users due to SSR?

The store is not shared, you create a new instance on every request. This is a rather persistent misconception, see also this answer for more info.

If you change something on the server, you can just reload only the data via invalidateAll.
If you change the data via a form action that uses enhance, this will even happen automatically.
You only have to make sure to use the data reactively, so everything gets updated in response.
